# snap svg add/remove link attribute

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am able to manipulate the xlink:href attribute of an SVG link element with ECMAScript like this :

```
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

myLink.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "xlink:href", "#");//add href attribute to the link

myLink.removeAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href");//remove the href attribute from the link
```

My question is : what is the correct syntax to do exactly the same thing with javascript or snap SVG?

Comment: JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript. You do it exactly the same way. Also the API is not part of ECMAScript. It's the [DOM API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which is language independent.

Comment: Felix, i'm aware that javascript is an implementation of ECMAScript, thus i've tried it :   myLink.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "xlink:href", "http://www.google.com");                                                                               it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In snap it's

```
element.attr("xlink:href", "http://google.com");
```

Snap will figure out the namespace for you

In Ecmacript (which is a synonym for javascript) its

```js
var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
var myLink = document.getElementById("link");
myLink.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href", "http://google.com");
alert(myLink.getAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href"));
```

```html
<svg><a id="link" xlink:href="http://stackoverflow.com"/></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, it works...one litle thing still bugging me tough : how to actually "remove" the xlink:href attribute from a link element in snap?                                                                                                  var xlinkns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";                                                                                               myLink.removeAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href");                                                                                                       In other words : can you translate the above ecmascript statement to

Comment: You could always breakout to normal DOM methods i.e. element.node.removeAttributeNS(xlinkNS, "href");

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work @Robert, `myLink.removeAttributeNS(xlinkns, "href");` seems does not recognized by snap (I used it inside ecmascript tag)

Comment: Aaah, it works thank you again! Sorry, i tought you type it wrong, so i just go without the `.node` part